# Vim: How to write a function that searches the current buffer?

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a function in Vim that searches the current buffer for a certain pattern and returns it. But, I'm failing horribly. Basically, what I want is a function that returns the (PHP) namespace of the file I am working in. The namespace is defined in the file itself:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;
```

What I would like is a function that returns the `Foo\Bar` part as a string. I.e. something that searches like `/namespace\s\([^;]\+\)` and returns the first submatch.

Edit: Here's the function I build thanks to the help I got:

```
func! PhpNamespace()
    let l:lnr = 0
    while l:lnr < line('$')
        let l:str = matchstr(getline(l:lnr), '^\s*namespace\s\+[^;]\+')
        if len(l:str)
            return substitute(l:str, '^\s*namespace\s\+', '', '')
        endif
        let l:lnr = l:lnr + 1
    endwhile

    return ''
endfunc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `searchpos()`, which gets you the start position; you then need to extract the text yourself. This is fast and easy, especially if you need to search forward / backward from the cursor position. With the `'n'` flag, the cursor position will not change. Otherwise, you have to save and restore the cursor position (`getpos('.')`, `setpos('.', saved_cursor)`).

For your problem, it looks like the namespace declaration is likely at the beginning of the file, and is limited to a single line. Then, you could also get individual lines with `getline(lnum)` in a loop and extract the text with `matchstr()`, and break out of the loop once you have it.

Comment: Great! Your solution looks fine to me; kudos for posting it; you're a pro!